# My netbook freezes everytime i turn on WLAN on Ubuntu

Tags: 11.04, freeze, atheros, wireless

Everytime i try to use WLAN connection on my netbook (Asus Eepc) my Natty freezes and i'm forced to restart and use my ethernet connection... How can i resolve this?

I've an Atheros board.

Comment: "A bug report (https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/module-init-tools/+bug/794291) has already been filed regarding this WiFi driver issue and the real courtesy of this particular post goes to the users there who have already detailed the steps on solving the problem." (http://www.techdrivein.com/2011/06/fixwifi-driver-breaks-after-update-in.html?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3A+techdrivein+%28Tech+Drive-in%29)

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution for my little problem.

**For recent Kernel versions you should do this (2.6.38)**

```
wget http://www.orbit-lab.org/kernel/compat-wireless-2.6-stable/v2.6.38/compat-wireless-2.6.38.2-2-ns.tar.bz2

sudo apt-get install build-essential linux-headers-'uname -r'

sudo apt-get remove lsh-server

tar jxvf compat-wireless-2.6.38.2-2-ns.tar.bz2

cd compat-wireless-2.6.38.2-2-ns

make

sudo make install

sudo make wlunload

sudo make btunload

sudo modprobe iwlagn bnep btusb rfcomm sco

sudo modprobe iwlagn

sudo modprobe bnep

sudo modprobe btusb

sudo modprobe rfcomm

sudo modprobe sco

sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart



**For older Kernel versions (2.6.32):**

wget http://www.orbit-lab.org/kernel/compat-wireless-2.6-stable/v2.6.32/compat-wireless-2.6.32.16.tar.bz2

tar -jxvf compat-wireless-2.6.32.16.tar.bz2

sudo apt-get remove lsh-server

cd compat-wireless-2.6.32.16/
./scripts/driver-select iwlwifi

make

sudo make install

sudo make wlunload

sudo make btunload

sudo make unload

sudo modprobe iwlcore

sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart

sudo modprobe iwlagn

sudo modprobe iwlagn bnep dtusb rfcomm sco
```

(http://www.techdrivein.com/2011/06/fixwifi-driver-breaks-after-update-in.html?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3A+techdrivein+%28Tech+Drive-in%29)

This has solved my problem!

Comment: Are you sure this is right? All the links you link to show bug reports for intel wireless and you have an atheros chip, and it's not even the same ubuntu version.