# wifi not working when on battery

Tags: wireless, ubuntu-netbook, internet

My wifi gets disabled when my netbook is not connected to a power source. Or more specific wifi is active but I can't browse the net when disabled. I'm using Ubuntu 11.04 on my asus eee pc.

I have posted a question regarding this on https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+question/166232

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you may find the answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/q/51261/15945) on this previous question **[My netbook freezes everytime i turn on WLAN on Ubuntu]**

Comment: na... not working....